# DNS to dispatch hostname to multiple ip

Tags: dns

Do you think it is possible to dispatch a query to `myservice.mysite.example` to multiple ip ?

Ex:

a query to `myservice.mysite.example`

will dispatch on theses ips

X.X.X.X
and 
 x.X.X.Y

the same query

I'm looking for a way to not create a dispatcher app by doing this directly in DNS configuration.

Comment: Yes, this is called [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) and is a stand feature.

Comment: It seems round-robin to round on ip and not dispatch on all ip

Comment: That's not how HTTP works...

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the DNS in your specific example is to match one name to one IP address.

You can publish multiple records for the same type and owner, let us see one example:

```
dig duckduckgo.com A +short
107.20.240.232
23.21.193.169
184.72.104.138
```

The name `duckduckgo.com` resolves right now to 3 IPv4 addresses.

It is typically used for load balancing (not fail-over) in a round robin fashion because typically again each time you query it you will get the set of addresses ordered differently.

This is all given back by the OS to the calling application... which then decides what to do.

Web browsers need to do **one** connection so they will pick up the first IP address they got, try to connect, wait a little, if it fails, try again with second IP, etc. until having tried all or having succeeded (this is a simplified algorithm, specifically because of IPv6 addresses too things are more complicated).

Web browsers do not connect to multiple IP addresses at the same time for the same name, so now just the DNS will not trigger an application to open multiple connections just because they were multiple addresses in the DNS.

Your needs are not very clear at this stage, nor it is very related to programming (you are not showing any code).